# "You may not rest now, there are monsters nearby" When there are no monsters nearby

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My bed is 10 blocks high, I've gone on spectator mode to check for mobs and there's none closer than like 8 blocks. Does anybody know what's up? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for edit reject I misread it

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange / Arqade :)

The Minecraft wiki states this, which I suspect you've seen:

> If a "monster" is within 8 blocks of the bed horizontally (in the X-
> and Z-axis), and 5 blocks vertically (in the Y-axis), the message "You
> may not rest now, there are monsters nearby" appears and the player is
> prevented from sleeping until the monsters leave or are killed. Most
> hostile mobs, as well as some neutral mobs prevent players from
> sleeping, as shown in the table below.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Sleeping

However as you pointed out, there were no mobs within 8 blocks.

Possibly, the game has been modified in some way? If you are playing on a server, most likely they are using a non-vanilla server like PaperMC. It's possible that this implements the logic differently.

Comment: I am playing on a server, but it's run by me. Running vanilla 1.16,5. Seems to be working now despite me not actually changing anything. Weird.

Comment: @JosephB - My server is using PaperMC, and I've seen it occasionally. I put it down to that server software doing something differently. It's interesting to discover that you are using vanilla. Would be good to hear back from you in a few weeks, to find out if it happens again.

Comment: @JosephB do any other players have access to your base? If they do, you're getting pranked, and somebody hid a mob (probably named "No Sleep For You") in the floor, and you haven't checked there yet.